# Include CloudFront-Viewer-Country in the AWS Cloudfront logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, aws-lambda-edge

Here's what I am trying to do. I have a file say (cat.jpg) in S3. Cloudfront is created with S3 as the origin. I am trying to capture location of the user who calls the cloudfront dns end point to access cat.jpg. Ex: https://myrepourl.company.com/cat.jpg. The user can be from any country across the globe.

In the Cloudfront cache behavior, header 'CloudFront-Viewer-Country' is added.
I have added custom policy in the response header policy and added header 'CloudFront-Viewer-Country' in this as well.

I have associated a lambda edge function (from us-east-1) and below is the code used.

```
'use strict';

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
   const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;   
   if(request.headers['cloudfront-viewer-country'])
   {
      print('country is '+request.headers['cloudfront-viewer-country'])
   }
   return callback(null,request);
};
```

**Question 1**
I do not see the header 'CloudFront-Viewer-Country' in the log file (stored in gz format) in logs S3 bucket. I see the IP address of the user. But I would like to see the country header as well.

**Question 2**
I see the header 'CloudFront-Viewer-Country' in the lambda edge logs. But I can view the lambda edge logs only corresponding to the region us-east-1 since I only have access to AWS resources only in this region. Will lambda edge logs be of any use to my requirement? If so, how can I capture lambda edge logs from all regions such that I get to see Country details of any user accessing the Cloudfront url.

Comment: Q1 - The country is not one of the standard log fields.
Q2 - Logs are saved per region. You need to check the logs in the region where the Lambda function was activated. If you only have access to us-east-1 logs, than you won't have complete data.

Comment: Thanks for the info Cristian. I was able to overcome region limitation to view lambda edge logs by adding code to upload log as text files to a common S3 bucket. When users call the cloudfront url from different regions, logs are accumulated in the same s3 bucket and I have written a middle layer code which performs some operations using the info in logs stored in s3.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to collect this data to generate a report/visualization? If so, one way you could do this out-of-the-box is using the [CloudFront Security Dashboard](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/introducing-cloudfront-security-dashboard-a-unified-cdn-and-security-experience/)

Steps in the console:

1. Navigate to the Security tab of your CloudFront distribution
2. Enable WAF (if not already enabled)
3. Enable logging in the "Request logs" section (if not already enabled)
4. Add a filter by URI path to visualize the countries of viewers viewing that URI path

Figure 10 of this blog post shows you what the visualization will look like: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/introducing-cloudfront-security-dashboard-a-unified-cdn-and-security-experience/

If you need to do this programmatically, you can query CloudWatch Log Insights directly to pull the raw data (it's what the log analyzer in this security dashboard is doing for you in the console).

Comment: Thanks for checking this. However, I need a way in which, every time someone calls the cloudfront url, my application should be able to capture the user's country and create an entry in the database I am maintaining. Hence this should happen programmatically. Is there anything wrong in the way I have configured cloudfront? do you suggest any other way how I can achieve this through cloudfront.

Comment: I added a comment to your main question. Even if you generate logs where you manually add the viewer's country, you'll need an intermediate step to parse the logs and populate a database. If you use the workflow above, your intermediate step would be querying CloudWatch Log Insights to retrieve the data and populate your custom database.